# WiFi Dropped for One Second

Tags: android, wifi

I have an app that needs to know when the device is connected. I am using BroadcastReceiver to receive the information and it works fine - BUT: Sometimes I receive a broadcast indicating lost of connection and after half a second a broadcast indicating that the device is connected.
Is there an API to handle such thing?

Thanks,
Nir

Comment: what is this API going to handle in this case?

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to tell the broadcast receiver to ignore such case...